# Not able to see 'Upcoming and Overdue' section on Activity tab for Case object

Tags: administration

Not able to see the 'Upcoming and Overdue' section on the Activity tab for Case object. But it is visible on Account Object.

[image: Attaching screenshot of how I see Activity tab on Case object]

[image: Attaching screenshot of how I see Activity tab on Account object]

Answer (score 1):

As per the standard functionality, you can see that section on Account but not on the case object. So to see your upcoming task on case object, you have to see under the open activity section under related list like shown in image :-

[image]